# Linux shell convert list of nested files into json

Tags: linux, macos, shell

I am developing on mac and use the following command to confirm file names to a json array:

```
ls **/*.test.json | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")[:-1]'
```

Which gives me the json array:

`['folder1/a.test.json', 'folder2/b.test.json', 'c.test.json']`

Which is exactly what I want. However, when executing on github action (with linux), the above command produces outcome:

`['c.test.json]`

And the files within folders are not included.

I confirmed that the folders where checkout successfully because `echo $(ls folder1)` gives `a.test.json`.

What is the best way to achieve what I want for the command?

Comment: For the `printf` variant, perhaps see if there is a way to enable `nullglob` but then if you have that, you can probably also enable `**` globbing with `shopt -s globstar`; it is often disabled by default.

Comment: @tripleee the `find` command actually worked! If you want to put it as an answer I will gladly accept it. My mac is on `zsh` and github runner is on `bash`. `**` works for `zsh`... Learned it the hard way. Also appreciate sharing the other materials too!

Comment: `**` actually works in Bash too; but you need `shopt -s globstar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**` is not a standard `sh` feature; your Github action probably requires a POSIX shell script.

To traverse arbitrarily deep directory structure with a shell which doesn't support `**`, try `find`:

```
find . -name '*.test.json' -print  | 
jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")[:-1]'
```

If there is only a limited set of directory levels, maybe try

```
printf '%s\n' */*.test.json *.test.json | jq ...
```

(Also [don't use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and perhaps see also [useless use of echo](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo).)

Both of these have some gnarly corner cases if you have file names which contain newlines; `find` could probably be coerced to handle that case, too, but I'll not complicate this answer further; perhaps see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 for a fuller discussion.

If your shell is Bash, `**` is available, but typically not enabled out of the box; you enable it with `shopt -s globstar` ... but perhaps it's better to stick to proper `sh` in case Github changes the default shell for Actions.